# How to write to a stream then to file

Tags: c#, stream, .net-3.5, filestream, savefiledialog

As part of another project, I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=netframework-4.7.2) article explaining how to bring up a SaveFileDialog.

But in the center of the code there is a comment that simply reads

> //Code to write the stream goes here.

and seeing as I don't know how to do this either I am at a bit of a loss.

In the end my code will be compiling a list of user selections, each separated by a newline character, and then saving that list to a .json with a name and a location specified by the user. The user will have the option to either create a new .json or overwrite an old one.

I'm not including any code snippets since right now, without the knowledge of how to properly write to a stream, there's really nothing to show that is relevant. If you would like more details though just ask. I'll do my best to flesh out my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job for you:

```
private void SaveString(string data)
{
    var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

    var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
    {
        DefaultExt = "json",
        AddExtension = true,
        Filter = "JSON|*.json"
    };

    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK || 
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveFileDialog.FileName)) return;

    using (var saveFileDialogStream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile())
    {
        saveFileDialogStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't acknowledge CopyTo as a real method, saying Stream doesn't contain it

Comment: @LordBaphelon what .NET Framework are you using? This is a feature introduced with .NET 4.0.

Comment: 3.5, I'm working with Unity as well, so that's as high as I can go I believe. Sorry for not mentioning this earlier

Comment: @LordBaphelon I updated my answer, taking your .NET version into account.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what this is doing, with this I should be able to convert string to bytes and put them into the buffer, then when this runs it will save said byte buffer to the user specified file location in the proper format?

Comment: Edited again, short answer sometimes, but not every time

Comment: @LordBaphelon I updated my answer. Hopefully it's what you're looking for now.

Comment: That looks perfect, but I'm having an issue when it goes to make the dialog, it's coming up with an error in Unity that the .ctor() method body is empty. Do you know anything about that or should I maybe go to a separate thread for Unity for that issue?

Comment: I'm not aware how those two could be related. You should probably make a second post. I tested my answer in a regular WinForms App and had no issues. If this solves your question, please mark it as the answer!

Comment: Yes this seems to be it aside from that issue, thank you very much for your patience and assistance!