# Unity Error: .ctor(): method body is empty

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-3.5, savefiledialog

This is a follow up question, coming from [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54696432/how-to-write-to-a-stream-then-to-file) about how to read and write from streams. The code that follows is the best answer from there:

```
    var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

    var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
    {
        DefaultExt = "json",
        AddExtension = true,
        Filter = "JSON|*.json"
    };

    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveFileDialog.FileName)) return;

    using (var saveFileDialogStream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile())
    {
        saveFileDialogStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
    }
```

The person who gave this to me confirms that it works outside of Unity, however when I try to have it run through Unity it throws the following error:

> InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Forms.SaveFileDialog: .ctor (): method body is empty

Any ideas? If you would like more details just ask. I'll do my best to flesh out my issue.

**EDIT**

Fixed first error it seems, but this uncovered a second, taking issue with the if statement seen above:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: http://answers.unity.com/answers/406235/view.html -- May be relevant to your issue.

Comment: @Chris Through that I did find what seems to be a solution, but I've now run into a second error, a NullReferenceException related to the if statement seen in the above code snippet. Any idea what may be causing that?

Comment: Well, how did you fix the first issue? My guess is whatever you did causes `saveFileDialog` to be `null`.

Comment: I reimported System.Windows.Forms.dll, but I took it from 'C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\2.0-api' instead of 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Client', so maybe it's the difference in api version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SaveFileDialog` class requires .NET Framework 1.1 or superior in order to run, as per pointed out at the end page of the [documentation you have linked to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog) in your original post.

**.NET Framework** is one of several runtimes provided in the .NET environment. Problem is: Unity **does not use .NET Framework** as its main runtime - it uses **Mono**, which is a lighter and portable version of .NET runtime, designed to run in multiple platforms. This is how Unity is able to execute .NET/C# code in iOS, Android, PC, macOS, etc.

So basically you cannot use the `SaveFileDialog` class in Unity without messing around with plugins which provide platform-specific implementations of a dialog for saving files. You would have to write  a plugin which could access that class, and even then, it would only be able to be executed in Windows-based platforms, as **.NET Framework is a Windows-specific .NET runtime**.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look for an alternative then.

Comment: Isn't [EditorUtility.SaveFilePanel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SaveFilePanel.html) meant for saving files in Unity?

Comment: OP you should take a look at this method suggested by @DStanley to display a "save file dialog" which runs inside Unity. Only downside is that EditorUtility is part of the UnityEditor assembly, which does not get compiled when you produce a final executable for your application/game. This means that it only runs inside UnityEditor, not in your final game's executable. If you are creating scripts which should only run inside Unity3D Editor, then that's definitely a great (and portable) solution.